# Performance of hazelcast using executors on imap with million entries

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

We are applying few predicates on imap containing just 100,000 objects to filter data. These predicates will change per user. While doing POC on my local machine (16 GB) with two nodes(each node shows 50000) and 100,000 records, I am getting output in 30 sec which is way more than querying the database directly.

Will increasing number of nodes reduce the time, I even tried with PagingPredicate but it takes around 20 sec for each page

```
IMap objectMap = hazelcastInstance.getMap("myMap");
MultiMap resultMap = hazelcastInstance.getMap("myResultMap");

/*Option 1 : passing hazelcast predicate for imap.values*/

objectMap.values(predicate).parallelStream().forEach(entry -> resultMap(userId, entry));

/*Option 2: applying java predicate to entrySet OR localkeyset*/
objectMap.entrySet.parallelstream().filter(predicate).forEach(entry -> resultMap(userId, entry));
```

Answer (score 1):

More nodes will help, but the improvement is difficult to quantify. It could be large, it could be small.

Part of the work in the code sample involves applying a predicate across 100,000 entries. If there is no index, the scan stage checks 50,000 entries per node if there are 2 nodes. Double up to 4 nodes, each has 25,000 entries to scan and so the scan time will half.

The scan time is part of the query time, the overall result set also has to be formed from the partial results from each node. So doubling the number of nodes might nearly half the run time as a best case, or it might not be a significant improvement.

Perhaps the bigger question here is what are you trying to achieve ?

`objectMap.values(predicate)` in the code sample retrieves the result set to a central point, which then has `parallelStream()` applied to try to merge the results in parallel into a MultiMap. So this looks like more of an ETL than a query.

Use of executors as per the title, and something like `objectMap.localKeySet(predicate)` might allow this to be parallelised out better, as there would be no central point holding intermediate results.